# GridView with the same height of the screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a grid that takes the same height as the screen (without scroll) regardless of how big or small each individual cell gets. Below is a code snippet of my current implementation. What should I add to get the desired result?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 15,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: List.generate(
          230,
          (index) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                ),
              )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you always need 15 columns? Is 230 a fix number or you want as many containers as needed to fit entire screen? Containers should have equal width and height (squares)?

Comment: @PeterKoltai
For now, I am trying to display 15 columns with 230 square cells. So, to answer your questions, all values are fixed and containers are squares.

Comment: So it means that the width of one cell is 1/15th of screen width, therefore the height is also 1/15th, and you have 230 cells. This will result in a determined height of all the cells. How do you imagine this to fill the entire height of screen?

Comment: If you want to fill the entire height, you will need a variable number of squares, calculated from screen width and height, and even in this case either you will likely have some unoccupied space at the bottom or the last row will not be complete. Only if you are lucky.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your GridView in a `Expanded` and set your physics to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`
Here's the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: GridView.count(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        crossAxisCount: 15,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: List.generate(
            230,
            (index) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                )),
          ),
    );
  }
```

if you want to set an exact number of Containers in  height you should give them custom height using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`.

Comment: I have tried running with the suggested code. The following error is bring thrown

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═══════════════════════════
Assertion failed:
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#bb7e6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT"

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold

Comment: maybe you have a Scaffold so you have to only wrap GridView in Expanded. I edited the code.

Comment: @auditore maybe try wrapping the `GridView.count()` in a `SizedBox()` with a height of `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`. This will set the height to be exactly the height of the screen.

Comment: @MehrzadMohammadi Now it throws the following the exception
`
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
`

Comment: @Hady
Although using `SizedBox()` do not throw any error/exception, all the cells do not fit into the given height. It just goes below the screen or have to scroll if the scroll is enabled.

Comment: @auditore and what are you trying to achieve? Also, could you please post a screenshot of what it looks like?